# button click to navigate from one view to another view in Ext Js - desktop application

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a panel, and 2 forms in it. 1st form has button in it. Clicking on the button in form 1 should show form2.

I have written a handler function for the button
var a = Ext.getCmp('mainpanel'); //it is the id of the panel
a.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('subform2')); //it is the id of the second form

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a layered panel an then add 2 panels to it

```
private JLayeredPane mainPanel = new JLayeredPane();
private JPanel form1Panel = new JPanel();
private JPanel form2Panel = new JPanel();

//other settings on the panel ...
//your form...

//on form1 button
JButton button1 = new JButton("go to form 2");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
           form1Panel.setVisible(false);
           form2Panel.setVisible(true);
    }
});
form1Panel.add(button1);


mainPanel.add(form1Panel);
mainPanel.add(form2Panel);
```

Comment: I am asking in Ext JS Sencha Architect. I am not sure about the above code, because I am not a developer but a QA.

Comment: Let me say once again, I used a panel and used a card layout for that panel so that it will display one view at a time. For that purpose i added 2 forms. Since the parent panel is given card layout. Currently subform1 displays. I added a button in subform1 and wrote a function which was mentioned in the priginal question, but it does not work.